# Toggle push menu collapse expanded

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code:

```js
$(document).on('collapsed.pushMenu', function() {
  $("#user_image_avatar").css('width', '30px');
  $("#user_image_avatar").css('height', '30px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
</a>
```

When I click it collapses and the image is smaller 30x30 but when I click back  and it expands the image does not resize to its original size 60x60 I tried something like this:

```
   $(document).on('expaned.pushMenu', function(){
        $("#user_image_avatar").css('width', '60px');
        $("#user_image_avatar").css('height', '60px');
      });
```

But it does not work, how can I reset back the element after expanding.
Also I am using admin lte free theme  for this..

Comment: Use `'expanded.pushMenu'` instead of `'expaned.pushMenu'` trigger event

Comment: your collapse code is working????

Comment: yes it works just fine but when I add the code with expand it does not work any more

Comment: OMG thank you not it works I don't know how I missed that :o